# Why do I get a blank (white) page when adding php code to my index.html page

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I add this to my index.html I get a blank page...

```
    <?php
echo PulsePro::css();
echo PulsePro::javascript();
?>
```

I do not have access to my php.ini file. I tried adding error reporting code to the page, didn't work.

Comment: Blank page indicates an error, [activate error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to find out the reason. You wrote you already did that, but it would show you the error, or your page is empty. We are gonna assume that the page is not empty.

Comment: Also you said index.html, php usually does not get executed if the file does not end in `.php`. Why do you use `.html`?